Need help on running the server of a django project connected with postgreSQL
When executing 'runserver' of manage.py, this error happens:
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1045, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 982, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 137, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 581, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 235, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 89, in applied_migrations
    if self.has_table():
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\migrations\recorder.py", line 63, in has_table
    with self.connection.cursor() as cursor:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 320, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 296, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 279, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 256, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 332, in get_new_connection
    connection = self.Database.connect(**conn_params)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\LABORATORIO\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xab in position 90: invalid start byte

This is my DATABASES dict from settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'superheroes',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '1234',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 60,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'client_encoding': 'UTF8',
            'options': '-c search_path=public',
        }
    }
}

i dont know what else to try, tried checking from pgadmin but im having another error

Are those literally your database settings (except for the password)?  The implication here is that you have a non-ASCII character somewhere in the connection string.  In Latin-1, 0xAB is the double left angle bracket, "«".
